# Removing all part of the binary image except the area with convexity defect

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0, image-segmentation, convexity-defects

I am using OPENCV 3.2 and I am working on a binary image.This is an image I am working on.

[image]

I am trying to remove everything except the hand area ( with convexity defects).
I tried blob detection to detect the blobs (other than the hand) but it's not showing anything. Any suggestions on how I should proceed?
The sample code for blob detection is:

```
Mat im; //has the above shown binary image
Ptr<SimpleBlobDetector> detector = SimpleBlobDetector::create();
vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
detector->detect(skin_binary1, keypoints);
Mat im_with_keypoints;
drawKeypoints(im, keypoints, im_with_keypoints, Scalar(0, 0, 255), DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS);

// Show blobs
imshow("keypoints", im_with_keypoints);`
```

Comment: do you want only tjr fingers, or thr whole hand? Be aware that there are many convexity defects in the image's contours!

Comment: just the fingers/palm. any suggestions?

Comment: if you would've wanted only the fingers without the palm I would've suggested you the answer of my inverse question: "how to crop away convexity defects" but yout question is: "How to detect a hand in a mask image with a lot of noise"